# how to obtain transformation matrix $A$ in $y = Ax + b$ notation?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, transformation, matrix-equations, affine-geometry

I'm trying to obtain original transform matrix $A$ and its translation vector $b$
From $y=Ax+b$ equation. I have original values of vectors before transform and translation $(x)$ and vectors after transform and translation $(y)$

I know that finding two unknowns with $1$ equation is not possible, but I think if I arrange $y=Ax+b$ in such a way that I can obtain $A+b$ or $A$ only? Is there is a way to find out?

And if I drop $b$ from equation and try to find out matrix $A$ only $y = Ax$ when vectors $y$ and $x$ $(2\times1)$ are known and matrix $A$ $(2\times2)$ is unknown, how I can do that? Because I can't take inverse of $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
$$\begin{align*}
\underset{2 \times 1}{y} = \underset{2 \times 2}{A}\times\underset{2 \times 1}{x} 
\end{align*}$$
Let $\underset{1 \times 2}{x^+}$ be the [Moore-Penrose inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Vectors) of $x$ defined by
$$x^+ =\dfrac{x^\mathrm{T}}{\langle x,x\rangle}=\dfrac{x^\mathrm{T}}{x  x^\mathrm{T}}$$
Then we get that
$$
\begin{align*}
A = yx^+
\end{align*}$$